# How to avoid constraint conflicts during rotation?

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working on a complicated constraints-based layout where I need to have 2 separate layouts for portrait and landscape.

When switching between them I'm getting a conflict, because the portrait constraints are not compatible with the landscape constraints and can only be applied after the size has changed, but the autolayout system tries to apply the old constraints to the new size (or otherwise).

This is demonstrated in the following "toy" example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box: UIView!
    var activeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "ViewController"

        self.box = UIView()
        self.box.accessibilityIdentifier = "box"
        self.box.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.box.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.box)

        self.box.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.box.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.box.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.box.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let initialSize = self.view.bounds.size
        self.reactivateConstraints(forSize: initialSize)
    }

    var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return [
            self.box.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.heightAnchor)
        ]
    }

    var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return [
            self.box.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.heightAnchor)
        ]
    }

    func reactivateConstraints(forSize size: CGSize) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.activeConstraints)
        if size.width < size.height {
            self.activeConstraints = self.portraitConstraints
        } else {
            self.activeConstraints = self.landscapeConstraints
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.activeConstraints)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        print("viewWillTransitionToSize")

        // HACK:
        //NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.activeConstraints)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
            print("viewWillTransitionToSize - animateAlongsideTransition")
            self.reactivateConstraints(forSize: size)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        print("viewWillLayoutSubviews")
    }

}
```

If you start in portrait and rotate, the code produces this output:

```
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewWillTransitionToSize
2019-08-28 16:04:22.067887+0200 TestALRotation[2484:12095036] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022ad130 H:|-(0)-[box](LTR)   (active, names: box:0x7fc12061b260, ViewController:0x7fc12061b460, '|':ViewController:0x7fc12061b460 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022ad4a0 box.right == ViewController.right   (active, names: box:0x7fc12061b260, ViewController:0x7fc12061b460 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022ad630 box.width == box.height   (active, names: box:0x7fc12061b260 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022ad770 box.height <= ViewController.height   (active, names: box:0x7fc12061b260, ViewController:0x7fc12061b460 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022836b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' ViewController.height == 375   (active, names: ViewController:0x7fc12061b460 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002281130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ViewController.width == 812   (active, names: ViewController:0x7fc12061b460 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022ad630 box.width == box.height   (active, names: box:0x7fc12061b260 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewWillTransitionToSize - animateAlongsideTransition
viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

The conflict happens, because the system is trying to perform the layout pass without asking my code to update constraints first (animateAlongsideTransition is printed after the conflict), so the portrait constraints are applied to the new landscape size (812x375), therefore the conflict happens.

Question:
Is it possible to avoid such conflicts in a generic way without disabling constraints temporarily and without fiddling with priorities?
Where should I call `reactivateConstraints()` from to avoid this?

Note: I tried to move the `reactivateConstraints()` before the `coordinator.animate` call, but that produces another conflict, because it tries to apply the new constraints to the old size (which is a conflict as well).

Some links related to this question, but not having the answer:

- http://corsarus.com/2015/adaptive-layout-part-3-orientation-specific-layouts/
- https://imnotyourson.com/ios-adaptive-layout-with-rotation-tips/
- [Correct way to programmatically update constraints when the device orientation changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597133/correct-way-to-programmatically-update-constraints-when-the-device-orientation-c/35203050#35203050)

Comment: I think the problem is with your constraints to begin with... *not* with trying to deactivate / activate. What are you expecting this layout to do? On launch in Portrait orientation, you get a red box constrained Top / Left / Right, and width = height... so, it fills about the top half of the view (on an iPhone 8). But what do you want it to look like on rotation to Landscape?

Comment: It is a toy example. The point is that you have a set of constraints A that only works for portrait, and a set of constraints B and that only works for landscape, and a proper way to switch them. In reality I have a bunch of constraints not just one, and ideally I'd like them to not cause a conflict, but just smoothly update from one set to another.

Comment: To be clear: I expect that the box is always square, and it fills the top part in portrait (height < screen height), and it fills the full screen in landscape (height > screen height). The activeConstraints cause no layout change, and should not cause any conflict either.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that works for me:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    print("viewWillTransitionToSize")

    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    print("updateViewConstraints")
    self.reactivateConstraints(forSize: self.view.bounds.size)
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

When `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` flag is set, the system calls `updateViewConstraints` soon after the size has changed, but before the layout pass, so the new constraints can be activated there, and the conflict is gone.